# WP-CLI doesn't run from cronjob

Tags: bash, cron

I made a bash script that uses [WP-CLI](http://wp-cli.org) and was intended to run from a cronjob. It runs fine from SSH, but fails when run through cron. During debugging I discovered that it was the WP-CLI part that wasn't running. It has no output at all.

I took just the WP-CLI portion of the script and tested it. I've confirmed that WP-CLI is indeed the problem:

/home/username/script/test.sh

```
cd /var/www/domain.com/ && wp post create --post-title="test" post-content="testing" --post-status=future
```

Here's an example of the cronjob that was added via `crontab -e` from the user account: (set to run every minute for testing purposes)

```
*/1 * * * * sh /home/username/script/test.sh
```

The script runs perfectly if run from SSH, but when run from the cron it has no output. I've tried adding `| mail -s example@foo.bar` to the cronjob entry. It sends the output to my email, but there's no output for the wp-cli command. I've also tried adding my username to the cronjob entry between the time data and the command to try to make sure that it was being run as my user. Also, I tried editing the bash script and changing it to `mail -s "cool story bro" example@foo.bar` and that worked fine, it just completely ignores WP-CLI.

I've been searching for the answer for about 12 hours now. I recently found this answer to someone else's question, which I think might help, but I don't know how to implement it. https://serverfault.com/a/95736

I just found this answer to someone else's question, and it seems like the way to implement the other person's answer, but it didn't work. https://serverfault.com/a/473961 I used exactly what he posted.

This is being run on an up to date Ubuntu server, by the way.

Please explain what the problem is and how to fix it. Or just if you know anything about it, comment or something, I'm pretty desperate at the moment.

Comment: Is it even valid to set a post status to future without providing a date?

Comment: @MichaelHampton While that's obviously not the issue, it doesn't work without it and it functions fine the way it is. I'm relatively new to WP-CLI but here's where I saw it: http://wp-cli.org/commands/post/create/

Comment: Have you tried to to add full path to `wp` command in your script?

Comment: @cycron: based on your: "... I've also tried adding my username to the cronjob entry between the time data and the command ...", please tell us if you're working with /etc/crontab or with per-user crontab (crontab -e), as related syntax is slightly different. Also, tell us which Ubuntu are you running on (to define a proper troubleshooting path).

Comment: @DamianoVerzulli if you read "Here's an example of the cronjob that was added via crontab -e from the user account". I said an up to date Ubuntu server, but it's with Ubuntu 14.10.

Answer (score 3):

Since the answer to my question was posted as a comment instead of an answer, I'm going to answer it myself to help other people find the answer to the question easier.

As per Cyrus's recommendation, I changed the above `test.sh` to:

```
cd /var/www/domain.com/ && /usr/local/bin/wp post create --post-title="test" post-content="testing" --post-status=future
```

Including the full path fixed the issue. However, I don't understand why a script run from a cronjob from `username` would be executed differently than if run from SSH as that same user.

Comment: Interactive shell vs. crontab is different, that's an entire discussion.

Answer (score 0):

I got the path from `which wp`
and updated in the cron which seems to have fixed the issues. but could any one let me know where we can setup the wp to run it self under the cron without defining the path?

`cd /home/master/applications/domain.com/public_html  &&  /usr/local/bin/wp cron event run --due-now`

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. For me, it was cPanel's Jailed Shell option that was blocking access to `wp`, `wget`, `curl`, etc when running crons. You can fix this by going to logging into WHM (:2087) and Account Functions >
Manage Shell Access. Make sure the account is set to "Normal Shell".