# WP cli command not running in crontab

Tags: cron, wordpress

I've encountered and issue adding  wp cli commands to my crontab.

The following works:

```
*/1 * * * * sudo -u web0 -i /usr/local/bin/wp theme update --all --path=/var/www/domain.com/web > /home/bob/themes.txt
```

But the following doesnt:

```
20 14 * * * sudo -u web0 -i /usr/local/bin/wp theme update --all --path=/var/www/domain.com/web > /home/bob/themes.txt
```

I was wondering why it wont allow me to set a specific time to execute, wildcard values don't seem to be an issue.

Im running the above in my root crontab.

Comment: Side note, probably unrelated: Why are you using `sudo` instead of setting the user directly?

Comment: This is one of many sites on the server and do to the server setup each site has their own web user. I used sudo so I can action all jobs from a central crontab instead of having to use seperate crontabs for each command. However even testing it in each users cron tab lead to the same result as above.

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong with both crontab lines. The second line should start at 02:20 PM. Did you take different timezones into account, if your server uses UTC and you are not?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback all the servers are based in SA so the above is in accordance with  Time zone: Africa/Johannesburg (SAST, +0200), this is also the time zone set on the server.

Comment: On the system crontab the first argument behind the date/time is the username that should run the task. E.g. `20 14 * * * web0 /usr/local/bin/wp` would run the task as `web0`. But as I said, that's just a side note and most probably irrelevant here.

Comment: Any help is appreciated so thank you for that. I have tested but returns a error command not found.

Comment: Your analysis is wrong.

I don't know what went wrong - you didn't provide any details of how you ensured the cron job was firing nor how you determined it was not working. You didn't provide the exact error message. You didn't say what distro and version you are using. And you probably shouldn't be running these from the root crontab.

Comment: Correct I am running this from the root Crontab that's the point. To create a central location for the crontabs for all sites web users. 

Regarding the other questions
Error message -> No error message as the command doesnt execute when a given time is specified
How do I know if it worked when using the latter format -> The plugins updated and the file I wrote the STDOUT indicated the updates where successful
Distro -> Ubuntu 22 LTS

Comment: Related: https://serverfault.com/questions/654785/wp-cli-doesnt-run-from-cronjob

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned I am still a novice, but I found the solution.

The issue was never the command but rather the crontab, even after changing my time zone on my server the crontab still made use of UTC time.

To avoid a just adjust the crontab to execute at the appropriate UTC time as SAST is 2 hours ahead.